# Forget remembered OpenID

Tags: openid

I accidentally clicked "Remember me" on a site requesting my OpenID. I'm using Gmail to provide it - is there a way to make it forget about that site?

Comment: Did you try to delete the cookies set by that particular page?

Comment: Yes. To no avail...

Comment: There must be a cookie that is still left over, try clearing cookies for gmail/google as well..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The process is simple.

1. Go to The [Google Account Security Page](https://www.google.com/settings/security?ref=srch), logging in to Google if necessary.
2. Beside `Authorizing applications and sites` click <kbd>Edit</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Revoke Access</kbd> for the site you wish to remove access for your OpenID